# What is the name of this part of a function?

Tags: java

I'm working out an exercise for a generalized programming course. This specific problem is in Java, which I am not familiar with. I can infer most of it but there's one part I don't know the name of to research. Here's the code (and yes, it's intentionally very obtuse for learning purposes):

```
class Reuse {
    Reuse Reuse(Reuse Reuse) {
        Reuse:
            for (;;) {
                if (Reuse.Reuse(Reuse) == Reuse)
                    break Reuse;
            }
            return Reuse;
        }
}
```

The third line (**Reuse:**) is what I don't understand. What's the name of that part of the function?

Comment: That is a label. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a label.

Labels are used with `break` and `continue` statements to make code execution jump to a specific line.

Comment: Perfect. I'll accept this as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Not to mention it's a bad practice to use labels.

Comment: @AnandMattikopp It's *often* a bad practice to use labels. Not always.

Comment: @Malt _Often_ is key. I'm yet to see a real use case for it's use in a high level language like java though.